# Setting the frame size of child UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController, which I'll refer to as `parentViewController` (which is itself inside a tab view controller, but I don't think that's relevant to this problem).

I'm trying to make this UIViewController display two child views in a split screen setup. One of the child views is controlled by a custom subclass of a `UITableViewController` (call it `tvc`. The other child view is controlled by a custom UIViewController, call it `dvc`.

In the `init` method of the `parentViewController`, I instantiate both child view controllers, `tvc` and `dvc`.

In the `viewDidLoad` method of the `parentViewController`, I add the child view controllers and child views.

If I add *only* the `tvc` child, it works fine: the table view takes up all available space, rotates properly, etc. This is what the code looks like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    _tvc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self addChildViewController:_tvc];
    [self.view addSubview:_tvc.view];

    NSDictionary *viewDictionary = @{ @"tvc": _tvc.view };
    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[tvc]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewDictionary];

    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
}
```

However, if I then add the `dvc` controller and subview, it stops working properly. The table view does not display, only a blank white view. Here's how it looks when I add the `dvc`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    _tvc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self addChildViewController:_tvc];
    [self.view addSubview:_tvc.view];

    _dvc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self addChildViewController:_dvc];
    [self.view addSubview:_dvc.view];

    NSDictionary *viewDictionary = @{ @"_tvc": _tvc.view, @"_dvc": _dvc.view };
    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_tvc]-[_dvc]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewDictionary];

    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
}
```

I'm not initializing the `tvc` with a frame, but simply letting the superclass `UITableViewController` handle that. In the `dvc` `loadView` method, I'm instantiating my custom UIView with a `CGRectZero` frame, since I assumed that the autolayout constraints would properly set the size.

What am I doing wrong that I can't show both child view's side-by-side?

Comment: have you tried adding constraints to added subviews?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do I have to call `addConstraints` on both of the child views as well as the parent view? I thought that the parent view was responsible for applying autolayout constraints to it's child views?

Comment: add a breakpoint after adding the constraints and then type in the console: `po [self.view hasAmbiguousLayout]`. This will check if your constraints are set properly. The constraints not being set properly might be your problem. LE - this works if your compiler is lldb

Comment: @MihaiAndreiRustiuc I've searched and I've searched, but I can't for the life of me figure out where to enter that command!

Answer (score 0):

I have similar situation, as there is no constraints after adding child controller.

I've added view that is used as a container for child view controllers. Here is code, I've used to add controllers:

```
[self addChildViewController:controller];
// menu view is container for menu controller subview (in your case tvc)
[self.menuView addSubview:controller.view];
// add constraints
[self pinView:controller.view toSuperView:self.menuView];
[controller didMoveToParentViewController:self.menuController];
```

The following function makes subview fill parent view

```
- (void) pinView:(UIView *) childView toSuperView:(UIView *) superView {
    UIView *addedSubview = childView;
    addedSubview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [superView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[addedSubview]|" options:nil metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(addedSubview)]];
    [superView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[addedSubview]|" options:nil metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(addedSubview)]];
}
```

Comment: So in your example, I would call `addSubview` on `menuView` for both child views (`tvc.view` and `dvc.view`)? What do I need to do to create `menuView`? Is it responsible for instantiating `tvc` and `dvc`? It's also unclear to me what the `pinView:toSuperView` function does - why can't we just add the constraints when the child view is added to the super view?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _tvc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self addChildViewController:_tvc];
    [self.view addSubview:_tvc.view];

    _dvc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self addChildViewController:_dvc];
    [self.view addSubview:_dvc.view];


    // For constraints
    NSMutableArray *allContraints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    CGFloat halfScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height / 2.0;

    NSDictionary *metrics = @{
                              @"viewHeight": @(halfScreen)
                              };

    NSDictionary *viewDictionary = @{ @"tvc": _tvc.view, @"dvc": _dvc.view};
    NSArray *constraintsVerticals = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[tvc(viewHeight)]-[dvc]|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:viewDictionary];
    [allContraints addObjectsFromArray:constraintsVerticals];

    NSArray *constraintsTvcHorz = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[tvc]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewDictionary];
    [allContraints addObjectsFromArray:constraintsTvcHorz];

    NSArray *constraintsDvcHorz = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[dvc]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewDictionary];
    [allContraints addObjectsFromArray:constraintsDvcHorz];


    [self.view addConstraints:allContraints];

}
```